# plot polynomial regression line with ggplot stat_smooth

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I'm trying to create a scatter plot with second degree polynomial regression line using ggplot:stat_smooth.
Here are the codes:

```
df.car_spec_data <- read.csv(url("http://www.sharpsightlabs.com/
wp- content/uploads/2015/01/auto-snout_car-specifications_COMBINED.txt"))

df.car_spec_data$year <- as.character(df.car_spec_data$year)

df.car_spec_data %>% group_by(year) %>%
summarise(maxspeed=max(top_speed_mph,
na.rm=T)) %>%  ggplot(aes(x=year, y=maxspeed,
group=1))+geom_point(color='red',   alpha=0.3,
size=3)+stat_smooth(method='lm', y~poly(x,2))
```

I got the following error message:

```
Error: Mapping must be created by `aes()` or `aes_()`
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need to name your arguments here, using `formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)`.  Right now you are trying to pass your formula to the `mapping` argument, the first argument of `stat_smooth`, and so the error follows.

Answer (score 7):

This works (for mtcars dataset):

```
df.car_spec_data <- mtcars
df.car_spec_data %>% group_by(cyl) %>%
  summarise(maxmpg=max(mpg, na.rm=T)) %>%  
    ggplot(aes(x=cyl, y=maxmpg, group=1)) + 
    geom_point(color='red',   alpha=0.3,size=3)+
    stat_smooth(method='lm', formula = y~poly(x,2))
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe add some explanation of why this works, much as in my comment above?  The key is adding the `formula` argument name specifically.

Comment: sure, as pointed out by @aosmith, need to add the name of the parameter  formula.